# How to create csv file during runtime using python?

Tags: python, sql, csv

I have a query,which returns the details of each and every student along with their name.I want to store those details in csv format with the student name as the file name using python.Is it possible to do this?If so,How? In the below example i have stored all the student details in a single file('Name.csv').But I want to store the details of each and every student in an individual csv file with the student name as the file name.How should i do it manually.Is it possible to create csv file during runtime?

```
 def WriteCsv(self,sql,StudentName):
  StudentNameResult=obj.cursor.execute(StudentName)
  f=open('Name.csv', 'w')
  TempList1=[]
  TempList2=[]
  for values in StudentNameResult:
   x=list(values)
   TempList1.append(x)
  QueryResult=obj.cursor.execute(sql)
  for Values in QueryResult:
   y=list(Values)
   TempList2.append(y)
  for StuName in TempList1:
    for StudName in TempList2:
     if (StuName[0]==StudName[0]):
      writer = csv.writer(f)
      writer.writerow(StudName)

StudentName="select Name from StudentCsv"
sql="select name,rollno,CourseName,Subject,empName,dept,block from   studentcsv
x=obj.WriteCsv(sql,StudentName)
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. When tagging an RDBMS please only tag the one you are actually using. I have removed these conflicting tags. If the RDBMS you are using is important to your question, please retag **only** the one you are using. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your code. Why don't you execute the query:

> SELECT name, rollno, CourseName, Subject, empName, dept, block FROM
>   studentcsv

And loop through the result rows while writing the data to a CSV with the student name.

```
for row in cursor.fetch_all():
    f=open(row["name"], 'w')
    # Write data to CSV
```